# Rails 3 respond_with for create returning json or location for JSON format when controller is in different module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.2.8. If you have this route:

```
  namespace :some_module do
    resources :some_models
  end
```

And the corresponding SomeModel is not in a module, then in SomeModule::SomeModelsController if you specify the location as the model instance (like in the create), then its assumption about the url will be wrong:

```
respond_with @some_model, location: @some_model
```

as it will assume that the url is some_model_instance_url instead of some_module_some_model_instance_url.

For some reason, when I try to get tricky and make a generic evaluation of what I think is the correct url in the create method (since this is in a generic module for inclusion in a controller):

```
respond_with @some_model, location: send("#{self.class.name.chomp('Controller').gsub('::','_').underscore.singularize}_url")
```

It results in: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"some_module/some_models"}` (which is plural, so there is no route)

This seems kind of confusing.

But just doing:

```
respond_with @some_model
```

when the controller is set to respond with json via:

```
respond_to :json
```

for me returns a 204 with no indication of the created instance's id, and it seems you need some indication that includes an ID for the client to make use out of it (creating something without returning an id is not good practice).

What is the right way to be using respond_with in a create method in a controller that is in a different module than the model and we want to return some indication of the created object's id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, if neither controller and model were a module, then to specify location you could use:

```
respond_with @some_model, location: @some_model
```

But, the controller is in a different module, so if you do that in the create method of the controller, it will try to evaluate the method some_model_url(id), but on the controller what is defined is some_module_some_model_url(id).

So, one of the ways you could do it would be:

```
respond_with @some_model, location: some_module_some_model_url(@some_model.id)
```

For a generic module that is included in your controllers, the instance methods might look something like this:

```
def initialize
  super
  qualified_controller_name = self.class.name.chomp('Controller')
  @model_class = qualified_controller_name.split('::').last.singularize.constantize
  @model_singular_name_url_method_name_sym = "#{qualified_controller_name.gsub('::','_').underscore.singularize}_url".to_sym
  class_eval "def #{@model_singular_name}(id); #{@model_singular_name_url_method_name_sym}(id); end"
end

def create
  @value = @model_class.new(...)
  @value.save
  respond_with @value, location: send(@model_singular_name_url_method_name_sym, @value.id)
end
```

That will return the location as a url in the Location response header, so in your spec test it might do this after the post:

```
location = response.headers['Location']
# now check that location looks correct, etc.
```

But, as a co-worker noted, you don't have to specify location if you define:

```
def some_module_some_model_url(record)
  some_model_url(record)
end
```

So, to add this generically:

```
class_eval "def #{@model_singular_name}_url(record); #{@model_singular_name_url_method_name_sym}(record); end"
```

And then you only need:

```
def create
  @value = @model_class.new(...)
  @value.save
  respond_with @value
end
```